# Typo3 6.0 - Content Object (Cobj) - Is it possible to display data from custom table?

Tags: object, select, typo3

I have a custom table "tx_myExt_domain_model_pub", and I want to display some records it contains.

For example, normally this is what I would do to display data from tt_content:

```
lib.footer = COA
lib.footer {
     10 = CONTENT
     10 {
         table = tt_content
         select.where = colPos = 10
         select.orderBy = sorting
         select.pidInList = 15
        }

  }
```

This is working perfectly, but I want to do the same thing with data from my custom table.

This is my actual TS and it's not working in my case:

```
lib.categories = COA
lib.categories{

   10 = TEXT
   10.wrap = <br/>

   20 = TEXT
   20.value = Publications
   20.wrap = <h2>|</h2>

   30 = CONTENT
   30 {
    table=tx_myExt_domain_model_pub
    select {
       pidInList = 32
       selectFields = uid,pid,publication
      }
    renderObj=COA
    renderObj{
            10=TEXT
            10.field=publication
            10.wrap=|<br/>
            20=TEXT
            20.field=uid
            20.wrap=|<br/>
      }
    }
  }
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: you have to adapt the select parts as well. imagine it as an api command for a regular mySQL select. if it doesnt work, you might post your table structure and actual ts

Comment: @Urs thanks for your answer, i just edited my post to put my actual ts, I don't know what I forgot, it just doesn't display anything... the table structure is a lot like tx_news_domain_model_news, but with some custom fields

Comment: You might need to add a renderObj to parse your select. See http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/articles/explaining-the-content-object.html for a useful example of a content object

Comment: Btw: if you enable the admin panel, you should be able to see the resulting query, so you can run it in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Urs thank you for your useful link. I tried to do as it says, but still it's not working... I edited my post adding my actual TS again, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code.
I tested the following code with the categories of ext:news, which seem to be comparable to your table:

```
lib.categories = COA
lib.categories{

   10 = TEXT
   10.wrap = <br/>

   20 = TEXT
   20.value = Publications
   20.wrap = <h2>|</h2>

   30 = CONTENT
   30 {
    table=tx_news_domain_model_category
    select {
       pidInList = 159
       selectFields = uid,pid,title
      }
    renderObj=COA
    renderObj{
            10=TEXT
            10.field=title
            10.wrap=|<br/>
            20=TEXT
            20.field=uid
            20.wrap=|<br/>
      }
    }
  }

page.10 < lib.categories
```

It worked fine!
Maybe there's something else wrong, either in your table or in your page ts.

Comment: yeah ok, at least it eliminated one possibility. I'll look into my page TS, I don't see what I did wrong. Thanks!